# White wine vinegar in sweet and sour sauce

Tags: sauce, vinegar

Can I sub white wine vinegar for white vinegar in sweet and sour sauce? Answer much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Sure. It will taste a little different, but fundamentally, the main thing is the acid - you'll just get some extra flavor (which you may or may not consider an improvement) from white wine, cider, red wine, rice, malt or balsamic vinegar, rather than white.

Answer (score 3):

Out of necessity, I've used apple cider vinegar in sweet and sour and was pleasantly surprised with the results. There will be a difference in taste, but it wasn't a deal breaker.

Comment: apple cider vinegar sounds like a perfect vinegar for sweet and sour. I prefer rice vinegar, but apple sounds really good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, the vinegar is just providing the acidity. Each vinegar choice will alter the flavor, but that could be either good or bad. Experiment and see what you like and you'll have your own sweet and sour recipe that is like no one else's.